# Horizontall Scrolling Card View with protruding adjacent fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I am trying to find a **way to do the below design in android**. But I am not able to find a solution for it. Can anyone give me a solution?

[image]

Comment: recycler view with horizontal layout or view pager

Comment: use `viewpager` or `horizontalScrollView` or `horizontalRecyclerView`

Comment: i tried that way but its not giving me the desired result. so if you have any example please do share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library for your app to get your Horizontall Scrolling Card View

**AppIntro** is an Android Library that helps you make a cool intro for your app, like the ones in Google apps.

[AppIntro git](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should use RecyclerView with Horizontal Layout. You can set Horizontal Layout for RecyclerView as following method :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myRList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myRList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

A good guide for using RecyclerView : [Using the RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

Comment: i tried it. but the problem is that its giving me a full screen horizontal view. i want it as the shows image.

Comment: You can set margins for RecyclerView for that purpose. 
Can you share your xml?